# For what purposes i can use App Links?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, applinks

There is a standard, called [App Links](http://applinks.org/documentation/), that allows to easy link & communicate between native mobile apps, browser, etc.

But for what purposes this can be used? As i understand, it is possible to define only one app per one page (it should be opened after user reaches this page, right?).

So, when i have my own website & native app, that solves same goals as website, i can publish app links metadata & native app will be opened automatically, if installed.

But.. what if i need to open native facebook/twitter/etc app? In theory, i can create separate html pages for each app on my web server, with its metadata. Is it ok to do this?

I mean, if i am not owner of app, i want to open?

Comment: A standard?  Do you mean a library?

Comment: @GabeSechan From facebook documentation: "App Links is an open standard..." https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/overview

Comment: An actual standard is something decided on by a group of interested industry players to be compatible, usually published by one of the big standards bodies like IEEE, W3C, ANSI, ETC.  It has exact specifications on how everything works, and may or may not have a reference implementation.  A library is a bunch of code that does some purpose, published by... well anybody.  What you posted is just marketing speak, it doesn't mean anything.  But calling it a standard in a technical discussion just sows confusion.